# Integral of exponent of random variable is continuous

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Let $X$ be a set, $F$ a $\sigma$-field of subsets of $X$, and $\mu$ a probability measure on $X$. Given a random variable $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, define $$\chi_f(t)=\int_Xe^{itf}d\mu$$ Show that $\chi_f$ is continuous and $|\chi_f(t)|\leq 1$.

I'm not sure how to start proving either statement. The function $\chi_f$ seems quite intangible, as it is an integral over $X$ and using $d\mu$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second part follows from $|e^{itf}|=1$.

For the first one, write $\chi_f(s)-\chi_f(t)=\int_Xe^{itf}(1-e^{i(s-t)f})\mathrm d\mu$.
Define $f_n:=f\mathbb 1_{\{|f|\lt n\}}$; using the inequality $|e^{ia}-e^{ib}|\leqslant |a-b|$ we get 
$$|\chi_{f_n}(s)-\chi_{f_n}(t)|\leqslant \int_{\{f\lt n\}}|1-e^{i(s-t)f}|\mathrm d\mu\leqslant |s-t|n,$$
hence $f_n$ is uniformly continuous.

Now, we prove that $\chi_{f_n}\to \chi_f$ uniformly. We have $e^{itf}-e^{itf_n}=0$ if $|f(\omega)|\lt n$, hence 
$$|\chi_{f_n}(t)-\chi_f(t)|=\int_{\{|f|\geqslant n}|e^{itf}-1|\mathrm d\mu\leqslant 2\mu\{|f|\geqslant n\}.$$

Comment: I have $|e^{ia}-e^{ib}|=\sqrt{2-2\cos(a-b)}$, so I can see that $|e^{ia}-e^{ib}|\leq \sqrt{2+2}=2$, but I can't see why $|e^{ia}-e^{ib}|\leq |a-b|$.

Comment: Use the mean value theorem with $\cos$ and $\sin$.

Comment: Actually, now you're confusing me. Do you mean $\min\{2,|a-b\|\}$ instead of $\max$? Also, it seems you only need $|\chi_f(s)-\chi_f(t)|\leq |s-t|$, so I'm not sure why you need the $2$.

Comment: Yes, it's the min. If we use directly the bound by $|a-b|$, we may have a problem because $f$ is not necessarily integrable. However, this problem may be handled by a truncation argument: take $f_n:=f\chi_{|f|\lt n}$, and show that $\chi_{f_n}\to \chi_f$ uniformly.

Comment: Okay, using your $\max\{2,|a-b|\}$ bound, I get $|\chi_f(s)-\chi_f(t)|\leq \sup_z(\max\{2,|s-t|f(z)\})$. How can I get the continuity from here?

Comment: I've edited, hoping it's clearer now.

Comment: That looks good, but in the last line, should it be $|e^{itf}|$ instead of $|e^{itf}-1|$?

Comment: When $f\geqslant n$, $f_n$ is $0$ hence its exponential is $1$.

Comment: Ah that's right, I forgot. Thanks Davide!