# Integral of characteristic function is infinitely differentiable

Tags: integration, measure-theory, derivatives

> Let $X$ be a set, $F$ a $\sigma$-field of subsets of $X$, and $\mu$ a probability measure on $X$. Given a random variable $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, define $$\chi_f(t)=\int_Xe^{itf}d\mu$$ We can [show](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569975/integral-of-exponent-of-random-variable-is-continuous) that $\chi_f$ is continuous and $|\chi_f|\leq 1$.
>
> Suppose $f$ is bounded. Show that all the derivatives $(d/dt)\chi_f,(d^2/dt^2)\chi_f,\ldots$ exist and are continuous.

We can write $$\chi_f(t)=\int_Xe^{itf}d\mu=\int_\mathbb{R}e^{itx}d\mu_f$$ But I'm not sure how to find its derivatives, since it is an integral with respect to $\mu_f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's nicer if you stay with

$$\chi_f(t) = \int_X e^{itf(x)}\,d\mu(x).$$

Differentiating the integrand produces

$$i f(x)e^{itf(x)},$$

which, since $f$ is bounded, is integrable, and dominated uniformly in $t$, hence by the dominated convergence theorem,

$$\chi_f'(t) = i\int_X f(x) e^{itf(x)}\,d\mu(x).$$

Iterate arbitrarily often.

Comment: I don't quite see how the dominated convergence theorem is applied here. Also, does this show that $\chi_f'(t)$ is continuous? (It wasn't easy to show that $\chi_f(t)$ is continuous, as you can see in the link.) Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what happened there. You have $\lvert e^{itf(x)}\rvert=1$, so the integrand is dominated by the constant function $1$, and you have $\lim e^{it_nf(x)}=e^{itf(x)}$ pointwise. DCT $\leadsto \chi_f$ is continuous. Here, if $\lvert f\rvert\leqslant M$, the $k$-th derivative is dominated by the constant $M^k$, so $i^k\int_Xf(x)^ke^{itf(x)}\,d\mu(x)$ defines a continuous function. To see that these indeed give the derivatives of $\chi_f$, note that the difference quotients $\frac{e^{isf}-e^{itf}}{s-t}$ are dominated (Mean value theorem for real and imaginary parts separately).

Comment: I understand up until the last sentence, where I'm not sure how you apply the mean value theorem. Is it like $\frac{\cos sf-\cos tf}{s-t}=(\cos)' uf$ for some $u\in (s,t)$? How does that imply the integral $i^k\int_Xf(x)^ke^{itf(x)}d\mu(x)$ gives the derivatives of $\chi_f$?

Comment: Yes, like that. Applying the mean value theorem shows that the difference quotient is uniformly dominated by a constant, hence the dominated convergence theorem says $$\frac{\chi_f(s) - \chi_f(t)}{s-t} = \int_X \frac{e^{isf(x)}-e^{itf(x)}}{s-t}\,d\mu(x) \to \int_X if(x)e^{itf(x)}\,d\mu(x)$$ as $s\to t$.